# What is a good name for functions like 'sum', 'max', 'min'?

Tags: design, naming

Suppose you have a function that allows you to find the sum/minimum/maximum of a data field:

```
void g(DataField* d, Operation* op){
  // applies op->f(...) on all fields of d
}
```

`Operation` would be defined something like:

```
struct Operation{
  virtual void f(...) = 0;
}

struct Sum : public Operation{
  virtual void f(...) { currentSum += argument; }
}

struct Max : public Operation{
  virtual void f(...) { currentMax = max(currentMax, argument); }
}
```

**What would be a good name for those many-to-1 operations as sum/min/max, and how should I therefore name `Operation`?**

Comment: "Aggregate" would be a pretty conventional name

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: @gnat: I ask for the "name of a concept", therefore the question should be ok.

Comment: aggregate aka fold aka catamorphism aka reduction

Comment: @JustinCave: That's pretty .NET-specific, I think. The usual name is "fold" or "reduction", as jk. mentioned. "Catamorphism" is the category-theoretical name. C++ calls it "accumulate".

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Not really.  That's the term that databases use for those functions.  As does Java.  Which isn't to say that there aren't other options.  But "aggregate' is used across a reasonably wide domain.

Comment: Aggregate is the generally accepted term for these functions.